# How to set default for tags that implemet arraylist using Phalcon tag

Tags: php, html, phalcon

Here is my code

```
$categoryData = ProductCategory::findFirst(
    [
        'id = ?1',
        'bind' => [
            1 => $this->request->get('id')
        ]
    ]);
$defaultData['id'] = $categoryData->id;
$languageList = Language::find('is_deleted = "no"');
foreach ($languageList as $row) {
    $categoryDescription = CategoryDescription::findFirst(
        [
            'category_id = ?1 AND language_id = ?1',
            'bind' => [
                1 => $this->request->get('id'),
                2 => $row->id
            ]
        ]);
    $defaultData['name'][$row->id] = $categoryDescription->name;
    $defaultData['description'][$row->id] = $categoryDescription->description;
}
print_r($defaultData);
$this->tag->setDefaults($defaultData);
$this->view->languageList = $languageList;
```

and my forms are like

```
{{form('cp/saveCategory', 'name': 'categoryForm')}}
    {{hidden_field('id')}}
    {% for language in languageList %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Name <small class="text-info">{{language.language_name}}</small></label>
        {{text_field('name[' ~ language.id ~ ']', 'class': 'form-control')}}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for language in languageList %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Description <small class="text-info">{{language.language_name}}</small></label>
        {{text_area('description[' ~ language.id ~ ']', 'class': 'form-control')}}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{{end_form()}}
```

But, that code does not work properly as i imagine, only 'id' field that filled properly. How can i make they fill properly?